# Need correct price regex (Java) - Mine doesnt work

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to make a regex, that checks if something is a price. I'm not good at regular expressions and this one give me a regex syntax error. It should check if the input is something like 13.3 or 0.1 or .4 or 6 or 200 or 3.04, which could all be interpreted as a price. I tried using Double.valueOf(String), however, this method accepts strings like 3.00, so more than 2 floating points.

```
private boolean validateAndSet(JTextField tf) {
    boolean isDouble = true;
    try { 
        if (tf.getText().matches("^[0-1]*(\\.)?[0-1]{0-2}$"))   {
            item.setAlertPrice(Double.valueOf(tf.getText()));
            return true;
        }
        isDouble = false;
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        isDouble = false;
    } finally {
        if (!isDouble) {
            System.out.println("Not a price;");
            tf.setText("0.00");
        }

    }
    return isDouble;
}
```

Comment: If you are using `Double` to store price, you are cheating the users of your application.

Comment: It is plainly wrong to store prices as a plain floating point. In Java you should always use `BigDecimal`.

Comment: `^[0-1]*` means your "price" can only ever be zeroes and ones (or nothing) prior to the decimal.

Comment: @BrianRoach Yes, that was dumb, saw it immediately.

Comment: @RohinJain how do you mean that it is cheating?

Comment: @user1924422 - read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency for why you're going to cheat people :)

Comment: Because you searching for prices without a specific currency, be warned: not every current is of this format. For example in Peru they have a currency of three parts: 1 Inti = 100 Centimos = 1000 Soles. ... ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrong things about your regex:

1. `[0-1]` -> this delimites a `0` or a `1`, you need to use `\d` to delimiter every number.
2. `{0-2}` -> this isn't correct, you need to use `,` instead of `-`

The rest I think is okay.

Comment: Thanks. The [0-1] was a brainfart on my side I immediately realized.

Answer (score 0):

Try `"^[0-9]*?(\\.)?[0-9]{0,2}$"`, instead.

Comment: @Javier detected the same issue (not 0-1, but 0-9).  Further, I think you need to make that * non-greedy as in my example.